# Matrix Multiplication in MIPS, Array Looping

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips

First time on stackoverflow, so please forgive me if I'm doing something wrong. I am trying to create the C code below in MIPS:

```c
void mm (int c[][], int a[][], int b[][])
{
    int i, j ,k;
    for (i = 0; i != 4; i = i + 1)
        for (j = 0; j != 4; j = j + 1)
            for (k = 0; k != 4; k = k + 1)
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j]
}
```

Here's my MIPS code:

```
            .text
main:
j mm

mm:
la $a3, array_A # base address for array_A loaded into $a3
la $a1, array_B # base address for array_B loaded into $a1
la $a2, array_C # base address for array_C loaded into $a2

li $t1, 4 # $t1 = 4 (row-size and loop end)
li $s0, 0 # i = 0; initialize 1st for loop
loop1: 
li $s1, 0 # j = 0; restart 2nd for loop
loop2: 
li $s2, 0 # k = 0; restart 3rd for loop
sll $t2, $s0, 2 # $t2 = i * 4 (size of row of c)
addu $t2, $t2, $s1 # $t2 = i * size(row) + j
sll $t2, $t2, 2 # $t2 = byte offset of [i][j]
addu $t2, $a2, $t2 # $t2 = byte offset of [i][j] 
lw $t4, 0($t2) # $t4 = 2 bytes of c[i][j]
loop3:
sll $t0, $s2, 2 # $t0 = k * 4 (size of row of b)
addu $t0, $t0, $s1 # $t0 = k * size(row) + j
sll $t0, $t0, 2 # $t0 = byte offset off [k][j]
addu $t0, $a1, $t0 # $t0 = byte address of b[k][j]
lw $t5, 0($t0) # $t5 = 2 bytes of b[k][j]
sll $t0, $s0, 2 # $t0 = i * 4 (size of row of a)
addu $t0, $t0, $s2 # $t0 = i * size(row) + k
sll $t0, $t0, 2 # $t0 = byte offset of [i][k]
addu $t0, $a3, $t0 # $t0 = byte address of a[i][k]
lw $t6, 0($t0) # $t6 = 2 bytes of a[i][k]
mul $t5, $t6, $t5 # $t5 = a[i][k] * b[k][j]
add $t4, $t4, $t5 # $t4 = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j]
addiu $s2, $s2, 1 # $k = k + 1
bne $s2, $t1, loop3 #if (k != 4) go to loop3
sw $t4, 0($a2) # c[i][j] = $t4 
#----------TEST-------------
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, ($a2)
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, new_row
syscall
#----------TEST-------------

addiu $s1, $s1, 1 # $j = j + 1
addi $a2, $a2, 4
bne $s1, $t1, loop2 # if (j != 4) go to loop2

addiu $s0, $s0, 1 # $i = i + 1
bne $s0, $t1, loop1 # if (i != 32) go to L1 

Exit: 
li $v0, 10 #exits
syscall

    .data 
    array_A: .word 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    array_B: .word 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
    array_C: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    output_row_string_C: .asciiz "Matrix C Output Row "
    colon_string: .asciiz ": 
    space_string: .asciiz " "
    new_row: .asciiz "\n"
    char_space: .space 2
```

The output I am expecting is an array of all 8's. I will reformat this later to become a 4x4 matrix. However, I have placed a syscall where the values of the array are printing and I am getting some garbage:

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
1126201457
544503160
536885768
8
8
8
8
```

I am trying to make sure the right values are being multiplied together and stored but I'm not sure if there is some problem in the data allocation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Clarify your question, please. What is the desired behaviour? What errors do you receive?

Comment: _"I am not sure if I should be using `lw` and `sw`"_. You should use the instructions that match the data you're reading and writing. If the data is a byte you should use `lb`/`sb` (or possibly `lbu` instead of `lb`). If the data is a word you should use `lw`/`sw`.

Comment: @kelin I restructured my question, the desired question is an output of 16 8's (eventually I'm going to format this into a 4x4 matrix) but I get garbage after the 9th 8. Currently, my code is compiling and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @Michael I've fixed the lw/sw errors, like I said the code should compile and run now.

Comment: @I believe my problem has to do with some of the strings in the .data section but I'm unsure of how to allign them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `addi $a2, $a2, 4` after your **#### Test snippet**. You are changing the base address of `array_C` which i think is not what you want.

Also, the arrays array_A, array_B and array_C have 17 elements instead of 16 (4x4), though that is not the cause of the misbehavior.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, I need to increment through $a2, otherwise the output is 1 8 and then 0's